# android build failed while deploying on eclipse juno

Tags: android

Hi guys, I am developing mobile application using work light plugin. I am getting error while I am deploying my common area... It's not build specific environment file in bin folder. I am getting this error while deploy the android application:

> FWLST1040E: android build failed:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   'C:...  \environments\base\android..does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you work this out? I got the same problem, but it was solved when I upgraded my Java version to Java 1.7.0_40 Oracle

My working environment:

Worklight V6.0.1
Latest Android SDK, as of this writing.
Java 1.7.0_40 Oracle
OS X 10.8

Comment: Nope, I spoke prematurely. The problem manifested itself by not building the separate Android project, as per the documentation. All problems solved after restarting my Mac, just restarting Eclipse didn't help.